# Can class methods be acessed from within an enum in that class in Java?

Tags: java, enums

Suppose I have a class that contains an enum in Java. Is it possible to access methods from the class that the enum is contained in? As an example:

```
public class Foo {

   private string getClassVal() { return "42"; } 

   public string getOtherClassVal() { return "TheAnswer"; } 

   public enum Things {

         ONE("One"), 
         TWO("Two"), 
         THREE("Three"); 

         private String _val; 

         private Things(String val) { _val = val; } 

         // This method is the problem
         public String getSomeVal() {
             return _val + this.getClassVal(); 
         }

         // And this one doesn't work either
         public String getSomeOtherVal() {
             return _val + this.getOtherClassVal(); 
         }

}
```

I know the enum methods above with comments do not work and result in errors, because of the context that `this` is in. What I'm looking for is something where I can access the "outer" class methods from within the enum. Or is this even the correct approach?

Is something like this possible? Or are enums locked up to outside methods, even within a class?

Comment: A simple test in eclipse would have made this obvious to you

Comment: Also, in the methods `getSomeVal()` and `getSomeOtherVal()`, the keyword `this` refers explicitly to the `Things` instance. When using nested classes, a method call with and without a `this` isn't equivalent - only the one without will look up the method in enclosing classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Because `enum`s are always `static` and therefore have no enclosing instance.

Obviously they CAN access `public static` methods of the enclosing class.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of whether they can access a `Foo`'s private methods if they're _passed_ an instance of `Foo`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - That is a good point - I think not but I would have to try it and see and I cannot at present.

Comment: They have no enclosing *instance* then, they certainly have an enclosing *class*.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Sure you can see: http://ideone.com/53GWDC. (Although it's a bit of a chore on a phone I suppose.) And it seems like nested enums behave like nested classes in that regard.

Comment: I tried creating an instance of `Foo` within the enum, and it turns out that I can access `protected` but not `private` methods.

Comment: @joshin4colours - interesting - but expected I suppose.

Comment: @joshin4colours Odd. The ideone example certainly compiles when accessing a private method.